# Store content-length as field value (aka in metadata of indexed docs)

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

We want to store the content-length of the crawler pages as metadata in the docs. I know we could set *http.store.headers=true* but I do not trust the http-headers of the server.

So we changed FetchedBolt to write

> ProtocolResponse#getContent().length

as value to metadata (in addition to the "bytes_fetched" metric).

Is there a way to get this value without changing the code?
(We could add an extra bolt between fetch and parse, hopefully there is a more simple solution.)

Answer (score 1):

This could be done at the protocol level but probably simpler to do it in the FetcherBolt. Would you mind contributing your code and opening a PR? Thanks